# If statements printing after a variable is entered

Tags: python, if-statement, calculator

I'm new to programming/coding and I'm using Python in my course. I have been asked to create a calculator that can add, subtract, divide and multiply. I'm trying to get the program to receive the numbers through input, then ask for what to do with it (eg. plus or minus) through a number entered and then give a result. I have the input stages of the code working but when I get to the last part I cant get it to work. This is the code

```
FirstNumber = "blank1"
SecondNumber = "blank2"
Device = "blank3"
FirstNumber = input("First number?")
SecondNumber = input("Second number?")
Device = input("Select a Number. Options are; 1.Plus, 2.Minus, 3.Times, 4.Divide.")
if "Device" == 1:
     print("FirstNumber"+"SecondNumber")
```

When it gets the the end it does nothing, help please.

Answer (score 4):

The condition `"Device" == 1` will *always* be `False` because no string is equal to an integer.  You probably want to change it to `Device == 1`, but this will (likely) still fail because on python3.x, `input` returns a string.  You probably want something like:

```
Device = int(input("Select a Number. Options are; 1.Plus, 2.Minus, 3.Times, 4.Divide."))
if Device == 1:
    print(FirstNumber + SecondNumber)
```

Of course, for the same reason, you'll probably also want to convert `FirstNumber` and `SecondNumber` into some numeric type ...

Comment: Just a note to the OP (I'm going to assume by 108k-rep that you know this too..): Please do not capitalize the first letter of variables. Those are idiomatically for classes. Up-voting because the answer logically is correct.

Comment: This works! Thank you, but I think the other problem you mentioned with the FirstNumber and SecondNumber thing is what I'm getting. It just puts both numbers next to each other eg. 4+7= 47

Comment: @NathanMcGrath -- Yep.  You'll want to "cast" them to some kind of number as well. . . e.g.  `float(input('First Number'))` as well.

Comment: Nathan, this is because Python interprets the "plus" sign to concatenate or add, depending on the type of the two matters. Just like you can not add an int and a str together, it will throw an error. You can however, cast the str "7" by doing what @mgilson has shown you with wrapping it in int(). int("7") + 6 will work. "7" + 6 will throw an exception.

Comment: And @Vincenzzzochi -- Of course you're right.  The (mostly) universally accepted python style guide is [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which lays out conventions for naming and line length, etc. etc.

Comment: So where should that be? Sorry I'm very new to this.

Comment: @NathanMcGrath -- It could be lots of places.  The _best_ place is to convert the string into a number as soon as you get it.  e.g. `FirstNumber = float(input("First number?"))` ... But you could do it later as well:  `print(float(FirstNumber) + float(SecondNumber))`

Comment: Ok, this seems to be all working now. One more question, what does the float function change here? I want to be able to understand it. Using something with no understanding would be a little counterproductive to learning haha

Comment: @NathanMcGrath python has a couple different types of numbers.  Things like `1.5` are `float`.  Numbers like `1` are `int`.  The builtin `float` and `int` can convert a string into the proper type.  e.g. `float('1.5')` results in the floating point number `1.5`.

Comment: So adding float lets python know its a number and displays it with a decimal point?

Comment: @NathanMcGrath -- More like the function `float` takes a string of characters that looks like a number (e.g. `'12345.2345'`) and actually turns it into a number in memory.

Comment: Thank you so much, you've been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

```
ops = {
    "+": lambda a,b: a+b,
    "-": lambda a,b: a-b,
    "*": lambda a,b: a*b,
    "/": lambda a,b: a/b
}

a  = int(input("Please enter the first number: "))
op =     input("Please enter an operator: ")
b  = int(input("Please enter the second number: "))

print("{} {} {} == {}".format(a, op, b, ops[op](a,b)))
```

Comment: I appreciate the code but the whole point is to solve the problems in my own code. It defeats the purpose to use yours, sorry